# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Specified firefox binary location does not exist or is not a real file: /usr/bin/firefox using GeckoDriver Selenium

Tags: java, linux, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I've writed a simple E2E test using Selenium WebDriver in Java.

When I run this test using `maven test`, intellij idea throw me an error:

> Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be: LINUX

My OS is openSUSE Leap 15.2 and for test I wanted to use installed Mozilla Firefox 78esr:

```
ac@icarus:~> firefox -v
Mozilla Firefox 78.2.0esr
```

Firefox is installed from openSUSE repo in a default location.

I have do a research and I've set a property for webdriver.firefox.bin:
`System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "path_to_firefox_binary");` to point it to installed firefox binary.

When I start this test again i've get a different error:

> [ERROR] userShouldOpenLoginPage  Time elapsed: 1.096 s  <<< ERROR!
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Specified firefox binary location does not exist or is not a real file: /usr/bin/firefox

For path I try:
`/usr/bin/firefox`, `/usr/lib64/firefox/firefox`, `/usr/lib64/firefox/firefox-bin`.

To get path for firefox binary I use whereis command:

> ac@icarus:~> whereis firefox
> firefox: /usr/bin/firefox /usr/lib64/firefox /usr/share/man/man1/firefox.1.gz

I try to fix this but nothing works, so I've downloaded firefox from mozilla site and point property to it.
Now binary is found, but IJ throw me another error:

> XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /home/ac/Pobrane/firefox/libxul.so:
> libdbus-glib-1.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> Couldn't load XPCOM.

When I try running firefox normally everything works great - browser starts.

I've tried checking if I have libdbus-glib-1.so.2:

```
ac@icarus:~/Pobrane/firefox> ldd libxul.so | grep libdbus-glib-1.so.2
        libdbus-glib-1.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libdbus-glib-1.so.2 (0x00007fe4dd115000)
```

```
ac@icarus:~/Pobrane/firefox> ls -allh /usr/lib64/ | grep libdbus-glib-1.so.2
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    23 05-16 18:45 libdbus-glib-1.so.2 -> libdbus-glib-1.so.2.3.3
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  162K 05-16 18:45 libdbus-glib-1.so.2.3.3
```

Lib libdbus-glib-1.so.2 exist (is a symlink) and it point to libdbus-glib-1.so.2.3.3 so why I get error "cannot open shared object file"?

Anyone have an idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

`webdriver.firefox.bin` is no more a valid property to be set through `System.setProperty()`

To set the path of the [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) binary you need to use an instance of `FirefoxBinary()` and pass it to an instance of `FirefoxOptions()` as follows:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriverLogLevel;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;

System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/path/to/geckodriver");
FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(new File("/usr/bin/firefox"));
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setBinary(binary);
options.setLogLevel(FirefoxDriverLogLevel.TRACE);
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com/");
```

Optimizing the code you can use:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/path/to/geckodriver");
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setBinary(new FirefoxBinary(new File("/usr/bin/firefox")));     
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
```

Comment: I have changed the way that path for binary is passed to a webdriver instance, but this not fix anything in my case :/