# Are there known problems for running geckodriver on Windows 11 or JRE 17?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am using :

- latest version of gecko driver ("0.32.2").
- recent version of firefox ("102.7.0esr (64 bits))

[image]

I set up the executables like this :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Dev\\tools\\geckodriver.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "C:\\Dev\\tools\\MyCompanyFirefox\\firefox.exe");

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

And I get :

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
Driver server process died prematurely.
Build info: version: '4.1.4', revision: '535d840ee2'
System info: host: 'GLA6008818', ip: '172.17.134.204', os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.6'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
```

Comment: try setting path to Firefox executable without the double "\\"  In this case not sure you need to escape.

Comment: Yes, I do. That's how java works and that's how geckodriver path is successfully found.

Comment: Do you have anything already running on localhost?

Comment: wouldn'tya know I just had this error popup randomly... I'm not running Windows 11 or JRE 17.  It seemed to disappear on the next run though.  Does this happen consistently for you?

Comment: Indeed, very consistent, I think I have a custom ESR version or maybe some admin setup prevents me to automate this enterprise Firefox. And I can't find any "portable" Firefox to unzip.

Comment: Just a wild guess really, but it might be caused by Firefox trying to download/install an update.  (even the ESR versions will patch security issues...)  You might try just turning off auto-updates or running it manually and applying the updates.

Comment: So you confirme there is no "portable" version of Firefox which doesn't need to run a ".exe" ?

Comment: Since it's open-source, I'd guess there is a version out there that doesn't need an installer to run.  It's still probably going to setup some things on the first run that are per-user.  At that point though you probably won't have a good test-case.

Comment: Chromium is available in a zip, but I can't start it on my secured professionnal PC, so yeah, I guess the policy running on my PC prevents me to use Selenium Webdriver.

Comment: I guess you could confirm that by opening a command prompt, navigating to your firefox directory (something like: "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\"...) and typing "firefox.exe -marionette"  This is how Selenium will launch it... and we can tell that your geckodriver was able to launch from the exception received.

Answer (score 0):

[`webdriver.firefox.bin`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64062807/7429447) is no more a valid property to be set through [*`System.setProperty()`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60061951/7429447).

---

### Solution

To explicitly set the location of the [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) binary executable you need to use the [`setBinary()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxOptions.html#setBinary(java.lang.String)) method through an instance of [*FirefoxOptions*](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxOptions.html) as follows:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;

public class genericTestFirefox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.setBinary("C:\\Dev\\tools\\MyCompanyFirefox\\firefox.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but I have exactly the same error output.

Comment: using these options

Comment: @Tristan You mean the same error _`Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure`_

Comment: exactly, just that